# python udf to calculate julian date from julian day

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to write a custom python udf to get the date if we pass julian day, which is a reverse of the below logic. Please advise.

```
def date_to_julian_day(my_date):
    """Returns the Julian day number of a date."""
    a = (14 - my_date.month)//12
    y = my_date.year + 4800 - a
    m = my_date.month + 12*a - 3
    return my_date.day + ((153*m + 2)//5) + 365*y + y//4 - y//100 + y//400 - 32045
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, '2017-03-01'), (2, '2017-03-02')])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=['idx', 'dt'])
df = df.select(df['idx'], f.to_date(df['dt']).alias('dt'))

My_UDF = f.UserDefinedFunction(date_to_julian_day, returnType=StringType())
df = df.withColumn('julian', My_UDF(df['dt']))
df.show()
```